# Taking Velocity Derivative wrt X

Tags: calculus, derivatives, fluid-dynamics, gradient-flows

I was looking at some examples in my Fluid Mechanics textbook, and it showed that
$$\frac{du(x)}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}(v_0 + v_0\frac{R^3}{x^3}) = -3\frac{v_0^2}{R}\frac{1+(x/R)^3}{(x/R)^4} $$
where $v_0$ is the initial velocity of the fluid and $R$ is the radius of a sphere where the fluid traverses across. Both constants. When I tried to derive it by myself, I got the following:
$$\frac{du}{dx} = -3v_0\frac{R^3}{x^4} $$
I do not understand how to reach the form that the book reaches, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v_0$ and $R$ are constants, your book cannot be correct. One can easily check that without writing out the calculations.

You need more information on those parameters. Perhaps, you can read more context around that formula.

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake on my end with respect to the context of the formula.

Comment: @RSM: thanks for the message. May I ask what book (author?) you are reading?

Comment: Fundamentals of Fluid Mechanics (Young and Okiishi). The derivative was also multiplied by the velocity, which is how it acquires that form.